# Iterating through tuples in a list

Tags: list, tuples, comparison, python-3.6

Let's say I have a list made up of tuples:

```
 stList = [('NJ', 'Burlington County', '12/21/2017'),
 ('NJ', 'Burlington County', '12/21/2017'),
 ('NJ', 'Burlington County', '12/21/2017'),
 ('VA', 'Frederick County', '2/13/2018'),
 ('MD', 'Montgomery County', '8/7/2017'),
 ('NJ', 'Burlington County', '12/21/2017'),
 ('NC', 'Lee County', '1/14/2018'),
 ('NC', 'Alamance County', '11/28/2017'),]
```

I want to iterate through each item(tuple) and if it already exists, remove it from `stList`.

```
for item in stList:
    if item in stList:
        stList.remove(item)
```

This doesn't exactly work. Basically, when I run this, if **any** item in the tuple is also in the list, it removes that item, so I get this:

```
[('NJ', 'Burlington County', '12/21/2017'),
 ('VA', 'Frederick County', '2/13/2018'),
 ('NJ', 'Burlington County', '12/21/2017'),
 ('NC', 'Alamance County', '11/28/2017')]
```

What is a better way to approach this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### You can compare the tuples directly.

Tuples with all entries matching will be considered equal.

```
>>> ('NJ', 'Burlington County', '12/21/2017') == ('NJ', 'Burlington County', '12/21/2017')
>>> True

>>> ('NJ', 'Burlington County', '12/21/2017') == ('NJ', 'Burlington County', '1/21/2017')
>>> False
```

### Do not remove items from a collection you are iterating over.

This can give unexpected behavior unless you are aware of how the removal is done and you are doing it properly. That is a different story.

Here are a few options.

```
seen = set()
result = []
for item in stList:
    # Tuple can be compared directly to other tupled in `seen`.
    if item not in seen:
        seen.add(item)
        result.append(item)

stList = result
```

Another possibility is

```
seen = set()
# Use a list to preserve ordering. Change to set if that does not matter.
first_seen = []
for i, item in enumerate(stList):
    if item not in seen:
        seen.add(item)
        first_seen.append(i)

stList = [stList[i] for i in first_seen]
```

**Edit** 
On second thought the second option is not as good as the first unless you need the indices for some reason (i.e., they can be reused for some other task) because `result` in the first case stores references and not copies of the tuples so it will incur more or less the same memory as storing indices to those tuples in `stList`.

### If ordering does not matter

```
stList = list(set(stList))
```

If you just want an iterable and have no need to index `stList`, then you can even keep it as a `set` object.

Comment: This worked very well. I agree now that trying to remove items from a list that I am iterating through is a bad idea. So, the `seen` is just a temporary holding spot for the comparison. Very nice; thanks!

Comment: @gwydion93 Yes. `seen` is a `set` to track the items encountered so far. If you have more knowledge/control over the data structure this step can usually be improved, for e.g., by working at the bit level or making your own custom hash function etc. If the problem is unconstrained and without any specific structure, in general it is hard to do away with something like the `seen` variable here.